# http://localhost:8888/wp-login.php is blank

Tags: wordpress, authentication

http://localhost:8888/wp-login.php is blank

Please help can't login

gives following error:

```
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WP_MatchesMapRegex has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 633

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Translation_Entry has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/pomo/entry.php on line 14

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; POMO_Reader has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 12

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; POMO_FileReader has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 106

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; POMO_StringReader has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 150

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; POMO_CachedFileReader has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 189

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; POMO_CachedIntFileReader has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 204

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WP_Widget_Factory has a deprecated constructor in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 403

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/class-wp.php:633) in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-login.php on line 418

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/class-wp.php:633) in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-login.php on line 431

Warning: Illegal string offset 'remember' in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/user.php on line 39

Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/user.php on line 39

Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_login' in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/user.php on line 54

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/user.php:54 Stack trace: #0 /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-login.php(770): wp_signon('', '') #1 {main} thrown in /Users/danmeyer/Desktop/B2W WP/wp-includes/user.php on line 54
```

Comment: show code of user.php

Answer (score 0):

Try manually resetting your plugins (no Dashboard access required). If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

If that does not resolve the issue, access your file and navigate to `/wp-content/themes/` and rename the directory of your currently active **theme**. This will force the default theme to activate and hopefully rule-out a theme-specific issue (theme functions can interfere like plugins).